# Making a GET request with data (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I am trying to make a GET request with data to an endpoint in my web application. However, I keep getting errors around GET requests not supposed to have data. I am not creating or updating a resource, but rather using data inputed client side to service the request. Here is my current implementation - am I thinking about this wrong? It throws an error `TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.` Perhaps it does make sense to make it a POST request? Thanks :)

```
export const fetchChartData = queryData => {
  return fetch('api/users', {
    body: JSON.stringify(queryData)
  })
  .then(res => res.json());
};
```

Comment: Your server side code will service the request. The get request will return whatever is specified by the code in the server. If you wanted to return all arrays that are not null, for example, then that code would be written on the server side and then called by the API. Do a GET on that url, with the correct credentials (if applicable) and you get back all arrays which are not null.

Answer (score 3):

The error is clear, but it all depends on the service you are consuming. Is it expecting a GET or can you change to POST?

If you can change to POST just add the method on your fetch:

```
export const fetchChartData = queryData => {
  return fetch('api/users', {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(queryData)
  })
  .then(res => res.json());
};
```

If you can't change to POST you will have to pass the parameters in the URL.

```
export const fetchChartData = queryData => {
  return fetch('api/users?param=value')
  .then(res => res.json());
};
```